# Removing .00 in configurable attribute price in Magento

Tags: magento

The currency I'm using in the Magento site I'm creating is Japanese Yen which does not have decimals in their currency. I've managed to remove it from my product page and cart.

By modifying app/code/local/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php inside format function like so:

```
$locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();
if($locale != 'ja_JP') {
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
} else {
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```

However, in the dropdown attribute I created, the decimal still shows. Like so:

> White - ￥3000.00

> Blue - ￥5000.00

In my dropdown attribute, how can I drop .00 at the end of the price? Also, is it possible to drop decimal for the admin without altering the database?

I've tried searching but sadly, Magento does not have a direct feature that would handle this. Or at least I haven't come across said feature.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to remove .00 by modifying configurable.js and product.js. It's not a direct solution but a workaround.

For each file, I split the price string removing any decimal points(.) and numbers succeeding it by using the split function of javascript. So I added something like so:

```
var a = price.split(.);
return a[0];
```

Using that, all the decimals have been dropped from my prices. Thanks for all your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this piece of code on beginning of `formatTxt` method in the same class you was editing:

```
if(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode() == 'ja_JP') {
    $options['precision'] = 0;
}
```

This will change the precision for prices in almost every place inside Magento (like Catalog, Checkout, even Administration).

Answer (score 1):

Check code of free [ET_CurrencyManager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html) extension to find a solution. You need to modify more that one funstion in Mage_Directory_Model_Currency. Also you need to modify precision for JS scripts too in Mage_Core_Model_Locale::getJsPriceFormat.

Or just use this extension to avoid core files modifications.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the Zend local format for JA (Japnese) is wrong, see file:-

```
httpdocs/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ja.xml
```

Line: 2953 (or just search for "0.00")

Update to the following:-

```
        <currencyFormats>
        <currencyFormatLength>
            <currencyFormat>
                <pattern>¤#,##0</pattern>
            </currencyFormat>
        </currencyFormatLength>
    </currencyFormats>
```

This will completely change the YEN display price to have zero decimals within the JA Locale.

**A couple of words of warning...**

1. The admin area if viewed in any locale other than ja_JP will allow a
   decimal price to be entered, entering a YEN price with a decimal
   position of anything other tha ".00" will result in a checkout price
   mismatch error.
2. It appears that Magento will always send prices to
   PayPal with two decimal positions and this will cause price mismatch
   errors when applying coupon or Sale discounts (Mage 1.6) - I'm
   currently working through this issues on this and testing against
   1.9 Version.